registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks does not work because it takes the NavHostFragment as Fragment, how to know the fragment that is open?
Follow-up to Jetpack Compose Hilt Inject ViewModel creation error with Jetpack Compose.
When I switch to another app (put the app that I am running in the background) and switch back to my app I want to show a bottomsheet with some results. The problem is that when I switch back the result does not show.
I tried using  registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks but the problem is that the fragment when I add logs is NavHostFragment and not the name of the fragment, in this way the condition is never true. What to do to if the fragment that is open is HealthExamFragment? Is there a way to take the name of the NameHostFragment, because when I make logs to show the name of the fragment it shows NavHostFragment.
if (!bottomSheet.isAdded) {
    if (!fm.isStateSaved) {
        bottomSheet.show(fm, "HealthExamResultBottomSheet")
    } else {
        fm.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
            override fun onFragmentResumed(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
                super.onFragmentResumed(fm, f)
                if ((f = this@HealthExamFragment)) {
                    fm.unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(this)
                    showHealthResults(item)
                }
            }
        }, false)
    }
}


If HealthExamFragment is a child of the NavHostFragment, you would need to register the callback on the latter's childFragmentManager
